# How can I clear the input field in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to clear the input text fields on the html page after I submit them via ngClick.

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head lang="en">
<title>Test</title>
<script>
 angular.module("myApp", [])
            .controller("defaultCtrl", function ($scope) {
                $scope.members = [
                    {name: "Joe", age: 24},
                    {name: "Jane", age: 22}
                ];

                $scope.newMember = {};

                $scope.addMember = function (member) {
                    $scope.members.push(member);
                }
            });
</script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="defaultCtrl">
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Age</td>
    <td></td>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr  ng-repeat="member in members">
    <td>{{member.name}}</td>
    <td>{{member.age}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="newMember.name" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="newMember.age" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-xs" ng-click="addMember(newMember)">Add</button>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is [a link to the sample](http://jsfiddle.net/user3673029/j3Sr4/5/) in jsFiddle.

I do not want the new name/age fields to appear as pre-populated with the name/age inputs that I just added after clicking Add.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reinitialize the newMember object and it would work

```
   $scope.addMember = function (member) {
       $scope.members.push(member);
       $scope.newMember = {};
   }
```

See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cmyworld/G6M8q/

Comment: I am trying to do the same reinitialization in a RESTful create call using ngResource, but it does not work. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: The most probable reason for this would be that you are reinitializng some other variable instead of the one binded to your view.